# How to change the value of an Arc<u64> in a struct?

Tags: rust

I can't increment a value inside a struct. I'm getting lots of different compile errors. I have an immutable reference to `self` and I can't make it mutable.

Here is my struct:

```
/// Proposer factory.
pub struct ProposerFactory<C, A>
where
    A: txpool::ChainApi,
{
    /// The client instance.
    pub client: Arc<C>,
    /// The transaction pool.
    pub transaction_pool: Arc<TransactionPool<A>>,
    /// The inherents pool
    pub inherents_pool: Arc<InherentsPool<<A::Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic>>,
    /// Current queue number
    cur_queue_no_ptr: Arc<u64>,
}
```

I want to increment `cur_queue_no_ptr` by +1

I tried this code:

```
let old_value_ref = Arc::get_mut(&mut self.cur_queue_no_ptr).unwrap();
let old_value = *old_value_ref;
let new_value = old_value + 1;
```

but got this error:

```
    152 |         let old_value_ref=Arc::get_mut(&mut self.cur_queue_no_ptr).unwrap();
        |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

I tried this code:

```
let copied_arc = Arc::clone(&self.cur_queue_no_ptr);
let old_value = *Arc::make_mut(&mut copied_arc);
let new_value = old_value + 1;
```

And another error:

```
150 |         let old_value = *Arc::make_mut(&mut copied_arc);
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

I also tried with `RefCell` but I get this errror:

```
   ^^^^^ `std::cell::RefCell<u64>` cannot be shared between threads safely
```

Apparently the examples in the docs will only work for variables but not structs, so how do you do it with structs?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MCVE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it much easier for us to help if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Arc` only allows you to gain a mutable reference to the contents if you have a mutable reference to the `Arc` object itself, and the `Arc` is the *only* one that points to its contents (all the others having been dropped already).

What you want here is one of the equivalents of `RefCell` for thread-safe coding, namely [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html). These will lock access to the contents while you borrow them, so that you can safely access them from multiple threads at the same time:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn example() {
    // defining the counter variable
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    // lock the mutex to borrow
    // it is automatically released when the borrow ends
    let mut counter_lock = counter.lock().unwrap();
    *counter_lock = *counter_lock + 1;
}
```

`Mutex` only allows you to mutably borrow, which makes it simpler, but sometimes not sufficient. `RwLock` allows you to immutably borrow as well, so that you can have either one mutable borrow, or multiple immutable borrows.

---

Alternatively, for numeric types it may be preferable to use [atomic types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html). These are specifically made for integers, and are faster than `Mutex` or `RwLock` (since they don't need to lock anything, changes happen  atomically). For a counter as above, the corresponing example would be something like:

```
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering},
    Arc,
};

fn example() {
    // define the counter variable
    let counter = Arc::new(AtomicU32::new(0));

    // increment the counter
    // no lock or mutable borrow is necessary
    counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
}
```